# Вылетает ошибка при попытке подключить Jstl

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jstl

Вечер добрый!

Прохожу курсы. Возникла необходимость подключить Jstl. Пр деплое на томкэте сервлета resume возникает ошибка: The absolute uri: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Работаю в Inteligi Idea. Почитал как подключить: добавить в WEB-INF папку lib и закинуть туда 2 библиотеки: taglibs-standart-impl-1.2.5 и taglibs-standart-spec-1.2.5. Закинул. Далее библиотеки подключил через project structure/libraries. Запустил - вылетает ошибка. Потом поискал у кого подобные ошибки были. Напиcали что надо добавить библиотеки  в File/projectStructure/Artifacts. Пофиксил все-равно вылетает.

Ссылка на репозиторий : https://github.com/Queetman/baseJavaHw1

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resumeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>web.ResumeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resumeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resume</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

list.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Список всех резюме</title>
</head>
<jsp:include page="/fragments/header.jsp"/>
<section>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${resumes}" var="resume">
            <jsp:useBean id="resume" type="ru.model.Resume"/>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="resume?uuid=${resume.uuid}">${resume.fullName}</a></td>
                <td>${resume.getContact(Contacts.MAIL)}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</section>
<jsp:include page="/fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

ResumeServlet:

```
package web;

import ru.Config;

import ru.storage.Storage;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ResumeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Storage storage; // = Config.get().getStorage();

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        storage = Config.get().getStorage();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("resumes", storage.getAllSorted());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что какую-то мелочь упускаю, но не могу понять какую. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Какие курсы, если не секрет?

Comment: JavaOps. Хорошие курсы.

Comment: Похоже не те библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой. И потерял много времени.
В общем в моем случае лечением стало добавления в папку lib в томкэте архив библиотеки jstl-1.2.jar.А в pom добавил  provided И все заработало.